# Characterization of linear system without base points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

My question is really simple. Where can I find characterizations of linear system without base points? I searched on Hartshorne's book without success.

Thanks

Comment: Given the tag -- do you want a statement for curves? Then one has a "numerical" criterion for complete linear systems which implies that if, say, $D$ has degree $\geq 2g$ then $|D|$ is base point free.

Comment: @Hoot Great! It's exactly I was looking for! Where can I find this result?

Comment: It's definitely in Hartshorne's chapter on curves. You could also find it in section 19.2 of Vakil's notes.

Comment: You might look for the phrase "generated by global sections," which is often how Hartshorne phrases it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll spell out the argument in Vakil in more detail. Let $D$ be a divisor on a smooth projective curve over $k = \overline{k}$.  Suppose that $\deg D \geq 2g$, where $g$ is the genus of $X$. Then by results in 19.2 Vakil, $D$ is base-point free if an only if for any closed point $p \in X$, $L(D-p) = L(D) - 1$. By Riemann-Roch, we get

$$\begin{eqnarray} L(D -p) - L(K-(D-p)) &=& (\deg D - 1) + 1 - g  \\
&=& \deg D - g.\end{eqnarray}$$
Since $\deg D \geq 2g$, it follows $\deg (K - D + p) \leq 2g - 2 - 2g + 1< 0$ and so $L(K-(D-p)) = 0$.  Hence 
$$L(D-p)= \deg D - g. \hspace{15mm} (a)$$ On the other hand, applying Riemann-Roch to $D$ and reasoning as above, we get
$$L(D)  = \deg D + 1 -g.\hspace{15mm} (b)$$
Combining (a) and (b) thus shows that $D$ is base-point free.

Comment: What do you mean by a "closed point" and what is $K$? thank you for your answer!

Comment: $K$ is the canonical divisor. I wrote "closed point" above because not all points on a scheme are closed in the Zariski topology (for instance the generic point of a DVR).